# PowerChute appliance 4.4.1 for ESXi issues 302 redirect to localhost after login

Tags: vmware-esxi, redirect, apc, virtual-appliances

I've been using PowerChute 4.3 network appliance on my ESXi host for a while now. I followed the instructions to download and install the appliance update to 4.4.1 this morning using the official tar.gz file. The update appeared to go well.

Now when I browse to powerchute:6547 it requests my login as usual. After I login the appliance issues a 302 redirect to localhost:6547/index.html. Obviously that doesn't work because localhost is my computer. If I try to browse to the appliance in a separate tab it just immediately redirects to localhost because I'm already logged in. I did try rebooting the appliance to see if that would help but it did not.

Any idea how to fix this or do I need to delete the appliance, install a fresh copy, configure it, and commit to never doing it by an in-place upgrade again no matter how easy it seems like it should be.

Edit: Setting up a new 4.4.1 appliance I notice that the configuration asks for a hostname. Maybe the original 4.3 has the hostname unset or set for 'localhost'. If I knew where that setting is held I could SSH into the vm and update that setting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution for this?  I'm way behind, but finding the same issue.  Looking for the settings to provide PS.  4.3 didn't have this issue, assuming it's new for the version.

Comment: Actually I never did get it working and had totally forgotten that it's broken. Thanks for the reminder. By the way, questions about a question should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: I think I ultimately reinstalled the VM appliance but I never finished configuring it. I just completed the configuration and it seems to be running fine now. Since I had upgraded from 4.3 it still had enough configuration that it's been protecting my servers anyway, that's why I had not noticed that I never really finished the upgrade.